# SP13 - Deploy and debugging stop work for other developers in project

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-web-part

My SharePoint team (*back-end and front-end developers*) work on project. 
Solutions are Visual Web Parts for *SharePoint 2013*. Where one developer deploy her solution or debug web part from visual studio stopping the work of others developers. How to solve this problem?

Thank you previously!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its common that SharePoint Sites stops working for a while till the deployment completes as it includes IIS Application Pool Recycle retracting/adding solutions and its assemblies into layouts folder.

Similarly for debugging, Visual Studio will attach an IIS worker process(`w3wp.exe`) to the specific application pool to debug the solution. So the sites will not work until that process hits the break point or while its executing.

To avoid stopping other developers work while debugging, you can create separate web application for each developer. So that each developer will have separate Application Pool and  when they can attach worker process to their own Application Pool(their own Web Application) without affecting others development.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7ee3858f-243c-4f43-a72d-3483ad1506f6/multiple-developers-debugging-on-different-web-apps-on-single-server?forum=sharepointgeneral

Answer (score 4):

Arun's solution would work, but another is to give each developer their own dev environment. So, each dev would have their own server to work on. If you haven't thought about this before, then it may seem extreme, but this is the common strategy people use. Create an image that's a single server farm, and let each dev have a copy of it to run on their workstation or on a server via hyper-v. Each dev then gets an environment that is unaffected by anything that other developers do. Then, set up another farm, and set up a process so that any code that gets checked in gets deployed to that server for testing purposes.